# why firebase is not deploying files placed outside public directory?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web-deployment, firebase-hosting

I've got these three files:

```
../project/public/index.html
../project/css/style.css
../project/js/func.js
```

I've linked "style.css" and "func.js" files properly in "index.html" and everything works fine when I test it locally, but when I deploy this project on firebase only "index.html" is deployed and the website does not work properly. If I place all three files in public directory, then all three files are deployed and the website works properly.
This is how firebase.json looks

```
 "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "publicWeb",
      "public": "public",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
```

How can I deploy these three files if they are placed in different directories?This is how I've linked files in "index.html"

```
<script src="../js/func.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase CLI will only publish files in the public folder, and nothing outside of it.  You should organize all your content under it:

```
../project/public/index.html
../project/public/css/style.css
../project/public/js/func.js
```

Use it like this:

```
<script src="js/func.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Comment: Makes sense, but begs the question: what does Firebase do with files which are not in the public directory but also not ignored?